# Perfmon not working on remote MSMQ Queue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon, msmq

I am not sure if this has been asked before, but I have done a lot of searching and come up empty. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong questions or missing something quite basic here.

I have 7 Public MSMQ Queues on a Server 2008R2 box in a Domain.

I can Terminal Serve onto the Server and run up PerfMon locally and add 7 Counters for "MSMQ - Messages in queue" and connect to the Queues to display a live graph view of all 7 queues.

On a remote (Win 8.1 Pro) computer, also in the same domain, I can run up PerfMon and add Counters to connect to the "MSMQ - Messages in queue" of the Remote Server, successfully. However, the graph never seems to even start to display any data, almost as if it cannot connect to the remote machine.

What is strange, is that I am sure I had this working briefly yesterday, but I could be wrong.

I have tried on other remote machines (Win 8.1 Pro and Server 2008R2) and have the same issue connecting to remote queues via PerfMon.

Is there something I am missing here?

My user is a Domain Admin so I should have rights to read the Queues.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Comment: "My user is a Domain Admin so I should have rights to read the Queues." Did you explicitly add this account or group? Default permissions won't include them. Can you supply specific list of permissions to an example queue?